# Printer wants to save as PDF prior printing

Tags: upgrade, printing, virtual-printer

Since I upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 lts, I am in trouble with the printer.
My printer is Epson Stylus C79 and  it is connected to an USB PORT.

When I want to print something, pops up a window asking to save as PDF, but I don't want to do that, I want to print direct with printer. The printer is a phisycal one and I've read that it happens when the printer is not phisycal.

Really I don't know what to do with this. It is disturbing because the process is very long in this way. I waste a lot of time.

I'd appreciate if somebody could help me with this.

Comment: Is the printer even ionstalled? `lpstat -p` will list all available printers for your Desktop then [edit] the result using code formatting to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.

You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.

From the command line,

`lpstat -t`

will show the total state of the printing system.